# Filter results by pivot data on laravel / eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to filter my data that match a specified criteria, see the example below.

##### user

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 2 | jim |

##### company

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Google |
| 2 | Stackoverflow |

##### user_company

| user_id | company_id | end_date | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 31/12/2018 | Left |
| 1 | 1 | 31/12/2020 | Fired |
| 1 | 2 | NULL | Hired |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | Hired |

I just wanted to know who and for which company is working actually.

User.php

```php
public function companies() {
  return $this
      ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'user_company', 'user_id', 'company_id')
      ->as('company')
      ->withPivot(['end_date', 'note'])
}
```

my query

```php
$users = User::with('companies')->select(['user.*']);
```

Already tried using `wherePivotNull('end_date')` either in model relationship and in controller query, no success.. I still miss something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `whereHas`, we can achieve that

```
 $users = User::with('companies')
        ->whereHas('companies',function ($query){
            $query->whereNull('user_company.end_date');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: that was my first approach, I get all data, debugging seems that the left join generated is somehow wrong..

Comment: i think wherehas will do inner join .so it will return all user where has companies with end_date null .just check again once with less recrods if you have large dataset

Comment: FYI; `whereHas` applies `WHERE EXISTS (...)` to the query rather than a `JOIN` and so will exclude `users` that do not have a `companies` relation. This does work as intended though and will return `Users` with a `null` `end_date`. If it's not working I suspect OP has a typo.

Comment: @Peppermintology.thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: thanks JohnLobo and @Peppermintology seems that this is working correctly. I was misleaded by the framework I have on top, I'm using [laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) to handle server-side works of DataTables jQuery Plugin